# jQuery keyup not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery and the Datatables plugin. Now I need to do something on a keyup event, but the browser my webpage is designed for doesn't handle the keyup event properly.

Any ideas?

```
table.columns().every( function () {
var that = this;
    $("input", this.footer()).on("keyup change", function(){
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
            that
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        }
    } );
} );
```

It works fine in modern browsers, not in IE7.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `.every()` might not be available in older browsers.

Comment: It does work with the change though, just not with the keyup

Comment: Provide your html source and jquery libraries that you have used. so that i can check and solve it for ie7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to test if `$("input", this.footer()).length>0` ? 
It seems that the DOM couldn't be completely loaded.

Try to use this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Your events binding here
});
```

Comment: The script I posted is only a part of the whole thing, so I do have the $(document).ready(function(){ });